# Conditional switch for ChartJS data

Tags: javascript, chart.js, jqvmap

I'm using ChartJS and JQVMaps in a website to create an interactive world map that displays info graphics when a user clicks on a region. Countries are grouped according to regions so they will highlight and unhighlight all together with this code:

```
var countryMap = {
"bi": "Africa",
"km": "Africa", //...

"cn": "Asia",
"kp": "Asia",
"jp": "Asia", //...

//...
};

var regionMap = {
    "Africa" : {
        "countries" : [
            "bi", "km"
             //...
        ],
        "name" : " Africa"
    },

    "Asia" : {
        "countries" : [
            "cn", "kp", "jp"
             //...
        ],
        "name" : " Asia"
    },
    //...
};

function getCountriesInRegion(cc) {
    for (var regionKey in regionMap)
    {
        var countries = regionMap[regionKey].countries;
        for (var countryIndex in countries)
        {
            if (cc == countries[countryIndex])
            {
                return countries;
            }
        }
    }
}

function getRegion(cc) {
    var regionCode = countryMap[cc];
    return regionMap[regionCode];
}

function highlightRegionOfCountry (cc) {
      var countries = getRegion(cc).countries;
      for (countryIndex in countries)
      {
        $('#vmap').vectorMap('highlight',countries[countryIndex]);

      }
      $('#vmap').vectorMap('highlight',cc);

}

function unhighlightRegionOfCountry (cc) {
      var countries = getRegion(cc).countries;
      for (countryIndex in countries)
      {
        $('#vmap').vectorMap('unhighlight',countries[countryIndex]);

      }
      $('#vmap').vectorMap('unhighlight',cc);
}
```

I'm trying to use a switch to set up different data sets for a pie chart that renders when the user clicks a region. This is the code within jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({});:

```
            onRegionOver : function (element, code, region)
            {
                highlightRegionOfCountry(code);
            },
            onRegionOut : function (element, code, region)
            {
                unhighlightRegionOfCountry(code);
            },
            onRegionClick: function(element, code, region)
            {
                switch (regionMap) {
                    case 'Africa': 
                        var pieData = [
                            {
                                value: 25,
                                color:"9e0b0f"
                            },
                            {
                                value : 75,
                                color : "#fff"
                            }
                        ];
                    break;    

                    case 'Asia': 
                        var pieData = [
                            {
                                value: 50,
                                color:"9e0b0f"
                            },
                            {
                                value : 50,
                                color : "#fff"
                            }
                        ];
                    break;    

                    case 'Europe': 
                        var pieData = [
                            {
                                value: 75,
                                color:"9e0b0f"
                            },
                            {
                                value : 25,
                                color : "#fff"
                            }
                        ];
                    break;    

                    case 'oceania': 
                        var pieData = [
                            {
                                value: 98,
                                color:"9e0b0f"
                            },
                            {
                                value : 2,
                                color : "#fff"
                            }
                        ];
                    break;    
                }

                new Chart(pie).Doughnut(pieData);
            }
```

The highlighting for the map works (for the most part) but the chart will not render at all. Am I using the wrong variable in switch() or does this require a totally different approach?

I have the full code up [here](http://jdillman.com/interactive_map/world_test.html). Thanks!

Comment: code has following error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setOpacity' of undefined jquery.vmap.js:633. This won't be helping

Comment: Yeah that would have to be an issue somewhere in the switch, it runs fine without it and I haven't messed with the JQVMap script at all.